# How to hide tabbar and navigationbar when tapped on the view

Tags: iphone

I was building an articles based application,i am having tab bar and navigation bar in my application.What i want to do is while my article is displaying when i tap on that view,the tabbar and navigationbar should hide and viceversa.
Please help me in this

Thanks for the responses,Finally i have used gesture method

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]

initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap)];

doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired =1;

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[doubleTap release];   - (void)handleDoubleTap {


NSLog(@"Single tap");
 if(firstTime)
 {
[UIView beginAnimations: @"moveField"context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460.0f);
tabBar.hidden=YES;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
     firstTime=NO;
 }
else {
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"moveField"context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    //[self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 372);
    tabBar.hidden=NO;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    firstTime=YES;
}
```

Now iam getting this when i tap on the screen...Is it possible  to hide the tabbar and navigationbar wheni scroll the view and vice versa....Please help me in this

Comment: You can hide navigation bar when you tab on view but problem with hide tabbar , when you hide tabbar its show the screen view on which tabbar is implement, If you show article in next view then you can hide proper view then view size is320*460 else 320*411 after hide tab bar

Answer (score 1):

Use one BOOL variable i called it firstTime in .h file

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if(firstTime)
  {
   [self.navigationController hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];
   firstTime=FALSE; 
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;
  } 
else
{
   [self.navigationController hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];
   firstTime=TRUE;
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=FALSE;
}
}

- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
{
  if(firstTime)
 {
   return TRUE;
 }
 else
 {
   return FALSE;
 }
}
```

this will hide your Tabbar and NavigationBar on single tap and viceversa

Answer (score 0):

```
int DEF_BAR_HEIGHT = 40;

-(void)hideBars:(bool)value
    {
        // hide navigation bar
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:value animated:YES];

       //hide tabBar
       CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
       viewFrame.size.height += value ? DEF_BAR_HEIGHT : -DEF_BAR_HEIGHT; // Change this to the height of the tab bar
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];

       view.frame = viewFrame;

       [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
```

I'm not sure about DEF_BAR_HEIGHT value. Try 40 or 40 plus navigationBar height.